# Understanding Reacts new Context with nested modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Typically in my React App I'd use a single context item to store non changing values and redux to read, update and delete state.

My understanding of the new context api is that it can replace redux - however I'm struggling to understand how it works with nested modules.

For example, from the react docs I gleamed that the context should be created, managed and distributed from the top level.

Similar to this:

context.js

```
const defaultContext = {
    wrestlers: [],
    brands: []
};
export default defaultContext;
```

app.js

```
import defaultState from './context';

import { Wrestlers, Brands } from './components';

const GameContext = React.createContext(defaultState);

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = defaultState;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <GameContext.Provider
                    value={{
                        state: this.state,
                        actions: {
                            onAddWrestler: () => this.setState({ wrestlers: this.state.wrestlers.concat(extraWrestler) })
                        }
                    }}
                >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Unit size={{ xs: 1, sm: 1 / 2, md: 1 / 3, lg: 1 / 4 }}>
                            <GameContext.Consumer>
                                {({ state: { wrestlers } }) => <Wrestlers collection={wrestlers} />}
                            </GameContext.Consumer>
                        </Grid.Unit>
                        <GameContext.Consumer>
                            {({ actions: { onAddWrestler } }) =y> <button onClick={onAddWrestler}>Toggle</button>}
                        </GameContext.Consumer>
                        <Grid.Unit size={{ xs: 1, sm: 1 / 2, md: 1 / 3, lg: 1 / 4 }}>
                            <GameContext.Consumer>
                                {({ state: { brands } }) => <Brands collection={brands} />}
                            </GameContext.Consumer>
                        </Grid.Unit>
                    </Grid>
                </GameContext.Provider>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The difficulty I have is understanding how components that don't flow from this app file can use context - in the old style I'd simply declare my context usage in the component that needed it and it would grab it - this doesn't seem to be the case because I can't use an unused variable (GameContext) without either redeclaring it or recreating it.

Am I to believe that context sits at the top levels and then hydrates the entire app as props? I can understand this pattern as it untangles components dependencies on context coming in magically.

Comment: *Am I to believe that context sits at the top levels and then hydrates the entire app as props?* - if you used Redux, you're already familiar with the pattern, except there can be multiple unrelated stores (contexts). Context provider doesn't necessarily occur at top level.

Comment: Components, pages or routes would have containers that subscribe to the store. With this new context it seems like its impossible for containers further down to retrieve the context.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Can you provide a troublesome piece of code that would show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Context works with a nested hierarchy.

If App is is the top level component/provider, the consumers can only be its children.

You can export the consumer

```
const GameContext = React.createContext()
export const GameContextConsumer = GameContext.Consumer
```

You can now import GameContextConsumer in other child components

Comment: I think this is maybe what I've missed - the documentation doesn't make this clear. I'll give this an experiment and vote accordingly :)